# PyQt5 I want to show camera view to label

Tags: python, pyqt5

This is my frame:

[image]

I want to show camera view to label
Label object name is camera
But the program finished without showing anything
What is the problem? Why I cant show?
Code:

```
class Widget(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        loadUi("mainwindow.ui",self)
        self.v = QVBoxLayout()
        self.v.addWidget(self.camera)


        self.Worker1 = Worker1()

        self.Worker1.start()

        self.setLayout(self.v)

    class Worker1(QThread):
    ImageUpdate = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def run(self):

        self.ThreadActive = True
        Capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while self.ThreadActive:
            ret, frame = Capture.read()
            if ret:

                frame = cv2.flip(frame, 180)
                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                frame = cv2.resize(frame, (311, 221))


                image = QImage(frame.data, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0],frame.strides[0],
                                           QImage.Format_RGB888)

                self.camera.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))



    def stop(self):
        self.ThreadActive = False
        self.quit()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Widget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If that's exactly the code you're using, there's an indentation problem in `class Worker1(QThread):`, which should be at the beginning of the line. That said: 1. QMainWindow doesn't support setting a layout, do that in Designer (right click on an empty area and go through the "Lay out" menu); 2. `self.camera` is an attribute of `Widget`, not of `Worker1`, and you should not use it anyway as UI operations are never allowed from external threads. You have a signal, emit the image with that; 3. it seems clear that you're taking code from various sources and trying to merge them without ->

Comment: -> knowing how to do it; please read more carefully those sources and try to understand what they do, then patiently *study* the documentation of the related classes to understand how they work and how they should be used. Randomly putting things together won't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit break and
I solved my problem with this code:

```
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import cv2


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)

        self.camera = realTimeVideo(self.camera)
        self.camera.start()

class realTimeVideo(QThread):
    def __init__(self, label):
        super(realTimeVideo, self).__init__()
        self.label = label

    def run(self):

        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture("ig_At.mp4")

        #fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
        #self.out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 25.0, (640, 480))

        while (self.cap.isOpened()):
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            if ret == True:
                frame = cv2.flip(frame, 180)

                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                frame = cv2.resize(frame, (311, 221))

                image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], frame.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
            else:
                break
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: As already pointed out in my comment, you must ***NOT*** access widgets from external threads. UI elements are *not* thread-safe: while **sometimes** it might work, doing so is not only discouraged, but wrong, as it can cause lots of issues, instability and fatal crash to the program. Also, QPixmaps cannot be created outside the main thread. You *must* connect the `ImageUpdate` you removed to a function that converts the received image to a pixmap and eventually calls `self.label.setPixmap()`, and in the thread you must emit the signal with the QImage.

Comment: @musicamante Would you kindly give an example code that does the job? I am having similar issues myself...

Comment: @Netanel what similar issues? The OP had **a lot** of issues in their code.

Comment: @musicamante I am having trouble figuring out how to update a `QLabel` with an image from a live camera feed that is running on a different thread. Can you give an example how it can be done?

Comment: Then please create a dedicate question for that after reading [ask], reviewing the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648) and providing a proper [mre]. Remember that SO is not a forum, giving you an answer in this post would be completely off topic, and giving random example code based on a vague question is also against the rules and principles of SO.